# Group by a column in a data frame but summarize some of those groups to one group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
RECEIPT   USD    TYPE
      1 10.00   Paper
      2 12.00 Digital
      3  5.00    Note
      4 10.00   Paper
      5 12.00   Paper
      6  5.00 Digital
```

If I group the data by column TYPE I get this:

```
balance = df.groupby(['TYPE'])['USD'] \
                    .agg(['sum', 'count']) \
                    .reset_index() \
                    .rename(columns={'sum': 'TOTAL', 'count': 'COUNT'})

   TYPE TOTAL COUNT
Digital 17.00     2
Note     5.00     1
Paper   32.00     3
```

But what if I want to get the information for just the digital receipt and the remainder as one line. I know how to do it with another column in my original data frame, but maybe there is a more elegant way to do it.

The desired result:

```
   TYPE   TOTAL COUNT
Digital   17.00     2
Remainder 37.00     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using boolean masking

```
mask = (df.TYPE=='Digital').map({False: 'Remainder', True:'Digital'})
```

or, using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (which IMO is a more elegant solution)

```
mask = np.where(df.TYPE=='Digital', 'Remainder', 'Digital')
```

Both will yield

```
df.groupby(mask)['USD'] \
                        .agg(['sum', 'count']) \
                        .reset_index() \
                        .rename(columns={'sum': 'TOTAL', 'count': 'COUNT'})

    TYPE        TOTAL   COUNT
0   Digital     17.0    2
1   Remainder   37.0    4
```

---

For more than two groups, you can use `np.select` as `mask`

```
np.select([df.TYPE == 'Digital', (df.TYPE == 'Paper') | (df.TYPE=='Note'), df.TYPE=='Mail'],
          ['Digital', 'Paper', 'Remainder']
```

Comment: This is very nice. Very elegant. What if I have two types and one remainder? As far as I see, `np.where` can only handle two elements

Comment: I guess I found it by myself: `mask = np.select([
    (df.TYPE != 'Digital') & (df.TYPE != 'Paper'),
    df.TYPE == 'Digital',
    df.TYPE == 'Paper'], ['Remainder', 'Digital', 'Paper'])` Thank you!

Comment: @ErikSteiner exactly! I had edited the post with the `np.select` case, but its good that you figured out the solution too :) Glad I could help

Comment: I try to change the code to a more flexible way. Any idea how to have more than 2 types? n types? Because the code np.select() can be pretty exhausting for 10 types